# Why is docker build running a command in an intermediate container that is then removed resulting in the command being ignored?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Due to reasons I can't determine docker's default nameserver address applied to a Linux container results in not being able to resolve and external addresses. I am attempting to update the nameserver address by using the sed command on the resolv.conf file but after the command runs docker appears to remove the image on which it was run resulting in the nameserver not being updated.

When docker build creates a Linux container on my Windows machine the resulting container has a nameserver value in resolv.conf of 192.168.65.1. I can't resolve any uris with it set as such. I can't even ping google.com. If I update the nameserver to use Google's DNS, 8.8.8.8, I can then ping other hosts and successfully run the commands that started the issue (dotnet restore).

I built an image that copied my files into /src and then ran it interactively to attempt to debug. I fixed my issue by running the following commands

```
# copy resolv.conf because I can't run sed on it directly
RUN cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.temp
# make my change to the temp file
RUN sed -i 's/192.168.65.1/8.8.8.8/' /etc/resolv.conf.temp
# copy the modified file over original
RUN cp /etc/resolv.conf.temp /etc/resolv.conf
```

Running interactively in the container I can then successfully call dotnet restore on my src files.

However when I include these instruction in the Dockerfile and build the image the copy happens, the sed command happens on the temp file, and the copyover command appears to happen but the resulting image still has the original 192.168.65.1 nameserver value.

Adding this command after the second cp:

```
RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Confirms that when the cat command is run the original resolv.conf contents are intact.

Here is the relevant part of the build output:

```
Step 9/12 : RUN cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.temp
 ---> Running in cf8e037f5675
Removing intermediate container cf8e037f5675

 ---> 53f1c8bb86c6
Step 10/12 : RUN sed -i 's/192.168.65.1/8.8.8.8/' /etc/resolv.conf.temp
 ---> Running in 14b6a8381261
Removing intermediate container 14b6a8381261
 ---> 22039e11f812

Step 11/12 : RUN cp /etc/resolv.conf.temp /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in 46d295d869bf
Removing intermediate container 46d295d869bf
 ---> ea1a18576f87

Step 12/12 : RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in 6cb4726e58cb
# This configuration is written to the config.iso
nameserver 192.168.65.1
search mycompany.local
domain mycompany.local
Removing intermediate container 6cb4726e58cb
 ---> 5ad060514a74
Successfully built 5ad060514a74
```

I expect the built image to have the new nameserver value set from steps 10 & 11 but that's not the case, it looks like the work is happening but then the intermediate image is being discarded and I don't understand why and what the proper fix is.

Comment: what is the base image of the Dockerfile?

Comment: microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk

Comment: Using `sed -i` is utterly pointless here. `-i` itself tells `sed` to *create a temporary file*, write the changes to it, and then overwrite the original file with that temporary file. Why would you use that operation to *modify* something that is itself a temporary file, rather than using `sed -i` directly on `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy regarding why I create the temp file first instead of sed -i on the original resolv.conf. Changing a docker inode is not allowed according to the responder in the this unix.se question. I get the same behavior described in the question attempting to run sed -i on the originally mounted file.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404189/find-and-sed-string-in-docker-got-error-device-or-resource-busy

Answer (score 0):

Name-servers can be added to docker container by passing these to docker daemon.

In file /etc/docker/daemon.json, add `"dns":["172.16.3.241", "127.0.0.1", "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"]` or add `dns` like `--dns 127.0.0.1 --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4` to docker daemon.

Comment: I'm using Docker for Windows. I attempted to change the DNS Setting in the Docker Desktop client from Automatic to Fixed (8.8.8.8) with no luck. Per the Microsoft docs I also tried adding a config file with the following value: ```{
 "dns": ["8.8.8.8"]
}``` to C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\config.json but also no change. The resulting Linux container resolv.conf stil ends up with a nameserver value of 192.168.65.1

Comment: Just want to confirm, you have restarted docker after making changes to configuration.

Comment: I had restarted the Docker service with no change, I went ahead with a full reboot and rebuilt the image but the with no change in the resulting container.

Answer (score 0):

You can change a container's DNS settings after building its image, cf. [the Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/).

Minimal example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

CMD ["cat", "/etc/resolv.conf"]
```

In the same folder, run:

```
docker build --tag foo . && docker run --rm --dns-search=foo.bar --dns=8.8.8.8 foo
```

Output will show:

```
search foo.bar
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to change the nameserver in order for the build to successfully complete. Here's the order of ops:

1. Copy source files
2. Run dotnet restore (.net package manager)
3. Run dotnet build

If the nameserver stays the 192.168 value before when step 2 is run the package manager can't resolve the source and fails.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem. `192.*` being in your `resolv.conf` is the condition for `dotnet restore`? I'm not familiar with this package manager. Wouldn't `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf` solve your problem? If not, why?

Comment: The echo command itself does work, I think the issue is that docker immediately removes the intermediate container the command was performed in. From the docker build output: ```Step 9/10 : RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
 ---> Running in 57838da7f84c
Removing intermediate container 57838da7f84c```

Comment: Removing intermediate containers is a normal thing Docker does. You can avoid this using `--rm=false` when building the image. Although I don't think this is a good solution – why is the `echo` way not sufficient in your case?

Comment: Did you find a solution here? Did you try putting the `echo` part inside the same `RUN` section that `dotnet restore` happens, or whatever command needs the other DNS server?